# JBoss 6: timer starts when application is not fully deployed

Tags: dependency-injection, timer, ejb-3.0, jboss6.x

I have a problem at deploy time in **JBoss 6**.
My application contains a *Stateless EJB* with one method marked with the `@Schedule(hour="1")` annotation. Such a method uses another Stateless EJB injected by @EJB annotation.

```
@Stateless
public class AuditRecordCleanerBean implements AuditRecordCleanerLocal
{
@EJB
private RecordManager recordManager;

@Schedule(hour="1")
public void moveRecordsToHistoricTable()
{
recordManager.moveRecords();
...
}
}
```

Because the timer is persistent in JBoss, when I reboot the application server it can sometimes happen that the timer triggers when the EJB RecordManager is not yet deployed causing a NameNotFoundException.

In server.log I found the following warning:

```
WARN  [org.jboss.ejb3.TimerServiceContainer] (Thread-2) EJBTHREE-2193: using deprecated TimerServiceFactory for restoring timers
```

Could be this the problem?
How can I delay the first timer execution after the complete deploy of the application?

Best regards,
Fabio